# How do I make my entire website responsive on mobile?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I know I'm not very good at html5 but I am actively learning.I've been having trouble to make my website responsive on mobile browser. I was able to make it responsive on web browser on a computer.

Can anyone tell me how can I made it responsive and explain to me how that function works?

Thank you so much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Cayla.</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="CSS/main.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div class="img1">

        <div class="one">
            <div style="width:60%;background-color:#D8D8D8;margin-bottom:3%;">
              <!--  <svg version="1.1" id="sign" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="792px" height="612px" viewBox="0 0 792 612" style="" xml:space="preserve">-->
                <svg version="1.1" id="sign" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 792 612" style="" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">

      .st0{fill:none;stroke:#FDFDFD;}
      .st1{fill:none;stroke:#12100B;stroke-width:0.75;}

    </style>
    <path class="st1 GIfDAJwL_0" d="M864,204"></path>
    <path class="st0 GIfDAJwL_1" d="M426.357,291.773c-0.041-12.345-1.707-22.665-4.352-34.209c-8.392,4.478-13.649,40.339-13.631,49.989
      c0.034,17.964-1.063,41.607,6.963,56.455c8.124,15.025,19.178,4.285,24.85-7.853c5.971-12.777,7.685-22.798,7.881-37.559
      c-1.444,5.259-5.496,8.714-3.049,12.917c1.016-4.619,3.755-6.121,3.922-10.898c-0.027,4.104,0.264,7.119,2.795,9.768
      c1.506-5.469,3.623-13.664,3.172-17.732c-0.113,3.707-0.037,7.516,0.22,11.143c3.36-6.947,4.348-16.811,6.454-24.181
      c3.606,53.796,0.22,113.64,0.22,166.148c1.091-17.07-3.938-34.533-3.938-51.979c-0.004-25.875,1.787-50.906,3.004-76.584
      c1.389-29.324,11.799-55.735,15.406-85.365c3.484-28.619,3.25-56.957,3.25-85.942c0,20.127-3.17,40.157-3.85,60.265
      c-0.672,19.88-0.455,43.321,10.324,60.186c4.844,7.576,9.213,12.045,16.535,5.148c3.479-3.277,4.025-6.196,4.052-11.49
      c-0.541,3.818-2.303,8.03-1.189,11.883c0.229-3.271-0.647-7.569,1.188-10.189c0.972,3.261,0.131,11.245,5.246,6.779
      c3.205-2.798,8.143-3.789,12.846-2.784c2.629,0.561,16.42,6.282,18.992,7.717c13.344,7.443,38.292-0.675,52.428-1.938
      c19.37-1.731,18.325-3.814,37.57-6.666"></path>
    <style>.GIfDAJwL_0{stroke-dasharray:0 2;stroke-dashoffset:1;animation:GIfDAJwL_draw_0 7100ms linear 0ms infinite,GIfDAJwL_fade 7100ms linear 0ms infinite;}.GIfDAJwL_1{stroke-dasharray:1094 1096;stroke-dashoffset:1095;animation:GIfDAJwL_draw_1 7100ms linear 0ms infinite,GIfDAJwL_fade 7100ms linear 0ms infinite;}@keyframes GIfDAJwL_draw{100%{stroke-dashoffset:0;}}@keyframes GIfDAJwL_fade{0%{stroke-opacity:1;}95.77464788732394%{stroke-opacity:1;}100%{stroke-opacity:0;}}@keyframes GIfDAJwL_draw_0{7.042253521126761%{stroke-dashoffset: 1}36.15023474178404%{ stroke-dashoffset: 0;}100%{ stroke-dashoffset: 0;}}@keyframes GIfDAJwL_draw_1{21.596244131455396%{stroke-dashoffset: 1095}50.70422535211267%{ stroke-dashoffset: 0;}100%{ stroke-dashoffset: 0;}}
    </style></svg>
                <span class="border">
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="section sec1">
            <h1>About Me</h1>
            <hr size="1" color="#666" align="center" >
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, enim accumsan vim ut, unum noluisse phaedrum ea duo, ne quo voluptaria argumentum. Mel volumus adipisci ne. Eu eos dolorem salutandi euripidis. Vix perfecto deseruisse ex, option scriptorem an ius.
            </p>
        </section>
        <div class="img2">
            <div class="txt">
                <span class="border trans">
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section class="section sec2">
            <h2>Portfolio</h2>
            <hr size="1" color="#FFFFFF" align="center">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="aki0.png" alt="aki">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <video  controls>
    <source src="OpenVertices.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <a href="https://youtu.be/SfSKYra8aZw"><img src="Lancer.png" alt="Lancer"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="Naturalthinker.jpg" alt="NT">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <video controls>
  <source src="Circleoflife.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="Essentiel.png" alt="Es">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="Japan.png" alt="Es">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="black.jpg" alt="Es">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="content.jpg" alt="Es">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="icons.jpg" alt="Es">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="ss15.png" alt="Es">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="mens.jpg" alt="Es">
                </div>

        </section>
        <div class="img3">

        </div>
        </div>
        <section class="section sec3">
            <h1>      Contact Me</h1>
            <hr size="1" color="#666" align="center">
            <ul class="fa-ul">
                <li><i class="far fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
                    <div>info@hello.com</div>
                </li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-2x"></i>
                    <div>514.123.4567</div>
                </li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-2x"></i></i>
                    <div>Montreal, Canada.</div>
                </li>

            </ul>





        </section>
        <section class="section sec4">
            <h3>
        Copyright @2017.
      </h3>
        </section>

</body>

</html>





  body, html
{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    color: #666;
}
.img1,.img2,.img3
{
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.img1
{
    /*background-image: url('../Images/background.jpg');*/
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    min-height:100%;
}

svg.sign {
align-items: center;
margin-top: 50%;
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right:200%;
margin-bottom: 50%;
}

.img2
{
    background-image: url('../color.jpg');
    min-height:400px;
    opacity:0.70;
}
.img3
{
    background-image: url('../me.jpg');
    min-height:400px;
    opacity:0.70;
}
.section
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 80px;
}
.sec1
{
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #666;
    min-height:200px;
    min-width: 300px;
    align-content: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.sec2
{
    background-color: #282e34;
    color: #ddd;
    min-height:2250px;
}

.sec3{
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #666;
  min-height:200px;
  align-content: center;
}

.sec4{
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #666;
  min-height:20px;
  align-content: center;
}

h1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family:futurastf;
  font-size:1.25em;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color:#666;
  text-align: center;
}

h2{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family:futurastf;
  font-size:18px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

h3{
font-size:13px;
font-family:sans-serif;
 font-family:futurastf;
 letter-spacing:2px;
 color:#666;
 align-content: center;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 text-align: center;

}

p{
   overflow:auto;
  font-size:13px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
   font-family:futurastf;
   letter-spacing:2px;
   color:#666;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-align:center;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left:auto;

}
.txt
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 27px;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.txt .border
{
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;

}
.txt .border.trans{
    background-color: transparent;
}
/* Three image containers (use 25% for four, and 50% for two, etc)*/
.column {
  display:inline-block;
  float: center;
  width: 48%;
  padding: 5px;
}
/* NEW */
.column img{

 max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
/* NEW */
.column video{

 max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
hr{
  width: 40%;
}

.fa-ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left:0;
}

/* NEW */
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .column {
   display:inline-block;
    float: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  hr{
    width: 100%;
  }

  .sec2
  {
      background-color: #282e34;
      color: #ddd;
      min-height:900px;
  }

}


/* Clear floats after image containers */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
     .img-wrapper {
        width: 49.75%;
     }
     .img-wrapper2 {
        margin-left:.5%;
     }
     .img-wrapper3 {
        margin-top:.5%;
     }
     .img-wrapper4 {
        margin-top:.5%;
        margin-left:.5%;
     }

   .img-wrapper5 {
        width: 49.75%;
     }
   .img-wrapper6 {
    width: 49.75%;
   }

   .img-wrapper7 {
        width: 49.75%;
     }


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #666;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align-content: center;
}

li {
  clear:both;
}

li i{
  font-size:40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

li div{
  float:center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: This question seems a bit broad. I would recommend using a framework such as bootstrap or something similar to get started, then you can look into how those work re columns etc. Also, note that making something responsive on mobile vs on a computer is essentially the same thing, as all you're normally looking at is the size of the screen, so maybe you can just apply what you've already done but make it work for even smaller displays

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is, use the css framework like bootstrap.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

or

If you do not want to use framework, can use media queries.

/* Mobiles - 320x480px */

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  h1{
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

/* Tablets - 768x1024px */

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  h1{
    color: red;
  }
}
```

And try to check responsive view using 
http://ami.responsivedesign.is/

Answer (score 3):

You can use two things to make website responsive.

1. Bootstrap Framework to make it responsive for all big and small
   devices. See their documentation [Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)
2. Media Queries [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You can make the website responsive by using screen Media queries and add meta tag in the head of the html document.

media queries works like this: you add the screen size and then the styles inside of it

```
@media only screen and (max-width: **your screen size here**) {
  div {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

you can read more about it here:

> [Responsive Design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)
>
> [Using Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
>
> [some Screen sizes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a CSS framework like Bootstrap, Tailwind, or other (There are lots of alternatives)

Or you can use media queries if you want to write custom CSS by your self.